# Chef error after upgrading to Amazon Linux 2016

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Ever since I upgraded to Amazon Linux 2016, I get a Chef error where it says it can't find the repository.  I haven't changed anything else and on my other instance where I am connecting to the same repository but haven't upgraded the OS, everything still works fine.  Any ideas?

```
Error executing action `checkout` on resource 'git[Download Custom Cookbooks]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
---- Begin output of git ls-remote "https://github.com:CompanyName/repo" master* ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: fatal: repository 'https://github.com:CompanyName/repo/' not found
---- End output of git ls-remote "https://github.com:CompanyName/repo" master* ----
Ran git ls-remote "https://github.com:CompanyName/repo" master* returned 128
```

Comment: It seems to be using the wrong remote URL, it should be https://github.com/CompanyName/repo or git@github.com:CompanyName/repo

Comment: it def is the right remote.  until the upgrade, it worked fine.  the same remote on my other instance works fine.

Comment: when I use the slash instead of a colon, I get an error then as well so it def wants the colon.

Comment: Forget chef for a bit, check out `git remote -v` on the checked out repo

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing git syntaxes. You want `repository "https://github.com/CompanyName/repo.git"` probably, the colon is for the `git` and `ssh` transports, not HTTP(s).